# Взаимодействие C# WindowsForm ComboBox и Firebase

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, firebase, combobox

Основная проблема найти пример того, как в ComboBox Items вставлять ряд данных из базы Firebase, к примеру при нажатии кнопки

Comment: У вас два вопроса в одном: как получить данные из FireBase, как вставить данные в ComboBox. Это не хорошо, такое лучше задавать отдельными вопросами. Если на какой-то из них у вас уже есть решение, выделите конкретную проблему и приложите к вопросу фрагмент кода, который позволит воспроизвести вашу проблему и на его основе, предложить вам решение.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем класс

```
public class primer
        {
            public int code { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
```

Создаем `List`

```
List<primer> list = new List<primer>();
```

Далее коннектимся к БД и выгружаем полученные запросом данные в список

```
public static void GetFBData()
        {
            string connString = "User=SADMIN;Password=PSWD;Database=/base/base.gdb;DataSource=x.x.x.x;Port = 3050;";
            FbConnection fb = new FbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                fb.Open();
                if(fb != null)
                {
                    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(@"select name, code from database", fb);
                    FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new primer()
                        {
                            code = Convert.ToInt32(dr["code"]),
                            name = dr["name"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

И уже затем задаем откуда `combobox` должен брать данные

```
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

где `name` мы обращаемся к объекту`name` в нашем `list`

если хотим привязаться еще и значению, то можно так

```
comboBox1.DisplayValue = "code";
```

Если вам понадобиться больше параметров строки инициализации подключения к БД, то можете обратиться к [ресурсу](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/)